# Adéquation entre la formation du néologisme « misogynoir » en anglais et l'accord (aucun, genre, genre et nombre) dans son emploi en français ?

Tags: anglais, orthographe, accord, néologismes, suffixes

En lisant un article je rencontre pour la première fois le néologisme de langue anglaise « [misogynoir](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misogynoir) », mot-valise inventé par Moya Bailey entre 2008 et 2010 et signifiant la « misogynie dirigée vers les femmes noires »  ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/misogynoir)). En français on aurait une variante graphique avec hypercorrection du préfixe (*mysoginoire* et Wiktionnaire note de manière fort étrange « le mot *mysoginoire* est plus employé que le mot *misoginoire* »).

Le fait que la misogynie soit « dirigée contre les femmes noires » me fait me questionner sur l'emploi de « -noir » dans l'orthographe. On pourrait avoir l'emprunt intégral sans accord mais doit-on alors employer un article au masculin (*le*) ? Ou l'accord en genre (*-noire*) ou en genre et en nombre (*-noires*) mais j'ai une hésitation entre le premier qui permet aussi l'accord avec le genre du mot *misogynie* (féminin) comme si « noire » était un adjectif, et l'accord au pluriel.

Quelle variante orthographique est la plus représentative de la formation de ce genre de mot-valise, de son sens, pourquoi l'une serait meilleure, et a-t-on une comparaison avec un ou d'autres mots qui permettrait de le confirmer ?

Comment: *Myso* vient du grec *múso*, c'est une racine pour la souillure et la contamination donc ne pas à confondre avec miso, du grec *mísos*, la haine. Les graphèmes *y* / *i* posent beaucoup de problèmes !

Comment: I didn't look into Moya Bailey's *misogynoir* concept but it seems to be a noun. Adapting to French a noun that ends in an adjective will cause a lot of friction and dissonance - all the more so if the adjective relates to the object of the concept and not its subject. So I would say none of the above.